# How to pass queryset in django celery

Tags: django, django-celery

I'm trying to build Instagram bot using django. I want to implement django celery to run task in the background. Here I'm facing some problem.

task.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from projects.services.instagram_bot import InstagramBot


@shared_task
def lazy_post_link_1_task(post_url, current_user, bot_id, email, password, time_interval, comments):
    instagram_bot = InstagramBot()
    instagram_bot.comment_on_post(post_url, current_user, bot_id, email, password, time_interval, comments)
```

views.py

```
for bot in lazy_bots:
    lazy_bot_filter_comments = Comments.objects.all().exclude(botscomment__bot_id=bot.id)[
                                                   :int(no_of_comment_for_lazy_bot)]

    lazy_post_link_1_task.delay(lazy_post_link_1, request.user, bot.id, bot.email, bot.password,
                                                    lazy_bot_time_interval,
                                                    lazy_bot_filter_comments)
```

I'm facing error something like this
[image]

I didn't know what I'm mission

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a queryset to Celery task directly, because the task arguments must be serializable. Instead you can pass a list of object IDs to the task, and then run query 
from the task itself. Another possible option - using Django [serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/) or better [DRF serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), if you only need the data and ready to deal with it using mappings.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is not to pass model instances/querysets to Celery. Pass IDs and other info to build this query on worker side instead.

> Do not pass Django model objects to Celery tasks. To avoid cases where the model object has already changed before it is passed to a Celery task, pass the object’s primary key to Celery. You would then, of course, have to use the primary key to get the object from the database before working on it.

https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/